# What is the amount of stack memory allocated for execution by the Swift Compiler?

Tags: swift, heap-memory, swift5, stack-memory

I want to know the amount of stack memory allocated for execution by the Swift Compiler. Is it dependent on the native machine's RAM ? If yes, then how is heap memory allocated ?

Comment: The OS X command "top" comes to mind, indeed any tool for watching the OS that monitors this sort of thing. You need to open a separate shell windows obviously to execute it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. The `top` command and/or the macOS's Activity Monitor shows the Total Memory in use by the Xcode IDE alone and doesn't separately show for the Swift Compiler. Also, there's no segregation between heap and stack memory.

Comment: Did you investigate the command line interface for invoking the compiler? You might find some answers here, least you might be able to control this a little more precisely?

Comment: You might try some performance tools for the compiler too, checkout the WWDC2017 video on SceneKit, look at the end of the video in which they talk about tools to sort performance for example.